# Wait for cmd command to end before continuing

Tags: c#, cmd

I run a command from the command window like this:

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "/C " + command + "> " + userProfile + @"\cmdoutput.txt";
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
```

The next line of code reads the text file and manipulates the data as needed. However, if I don't wait for the cmd process to end it will read an empty text file. I have thought of:

- Not using a text file

  - This won't work due to other restrictions I have, it does need to be put in a text file
- Wait a few seconds

  - I don't know how long the command will take, and time-based solutions are generally bad anyway.
- Check if the command prompt process is running

  - The user may be running another command prompt for whatever reason

Comment: Take a look at the `Process` class.  I'm sure you'll find something there that will serve you well.

Comment: Also, research console redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `System.Diagnostics.Process` class has a method, [`WaitForExit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit(v=vs.110).aspx). As I understand your question, that should do what you're looking for.

You should be able to just do,

```
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

You can also pass an `int` for a timeout, if necessary.

This, of course, assumes that the application you're running will exit after it's done. If that's not the case (*reconsider that!*), you'll have to do something else, like polling.